# abaqus fortran in mpi mode gives different results using matmul

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I am using Fortran90 freeformat coding and intel ifort compiler to create a user subroutine that is than further used in a finite element calculation in ABAQUS.
This routine works just fine one a single core.
However when using it in parallel mode (MPI) the simulation crashes with (signal 11)
I tracked it down to the following codelines.
This will cause errors

```
BBAR1           = J**(-2d0/3d0)*( MATMUL( F1,TRANSPOSE(F1) ) )
```

where this version will do it:

```
BBAR1           = ( MATMUL( F1,TRANSPOSE(F1) ) )
BBAR1           = J**(-2d0/3d0)*BBAR1
```

It is driving my crazy. Does anyone has any ideas why that is?

Grateful for any advice

Comment: This way to small amount of information to diagnose the problem. Where do the variables come from? How much different are the results? How does the parallelization affect the variables shown above?

Comment: I know that it is way to less information. The variables come frome a continium mechanical (neo-hooke) material model implemented in fortran. Because I have a reference soltuion from the abaqus manual I could track the error down to these specific expressions. The error lies in between a range of 5% but induces the global solution to diverge.
How the parallelization works, that I do not know. One totally has to relay on ABAQUS and Intel to trust that they do the right thing... I only know that they are using the MPI for parallelization

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to this.
Today I randomly tried to downgrade my intel compiler version from ifort 14.0 to ifort 12.1.5
Now everything works just fine....
This really odd. Somehow the parallel solution in ABAQUS works not properly with the newest Intel release.